# Using a macro for entries loop

Tags: entries, sections, macro

I'm trying to use a macro to output a list of entries (and the title of a section), this is my code:

```
{% macro sections(sectionName)%}

    {% set index = craft.entries.section('{{ sectionName }}Index').first %}
    <h3>{{ index.getLink() }}</h3>

    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('{{ sectionName }}').order('title') %}

        {{ loop.first ? '<ul>'}}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a> {{ sectionName }}</li>
        {{ loop.last ? '</ul>'}}

    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.sections('about') }}
{{ _self.sections('information') }}
{{ _self.sections('galleries') }}
```

But this displays ALL entries. However, if I hardcode the section names (for each loop) it works, though not DRY.

This is my first attempt at using a macro, seemed like a good place to use one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want braces within braces.

You want something like this instead:

```
{% set index = craft.entries.section(sectionName ~ 'Index').first %}
```

Same needs changing in the for loop.

Comment: Gah! Of course! Thank you. And for the heads up on the ~